# how can i get a south african Identity document

Tags: south-africa

i would like to find out how i can get a south african ID if i have lived all my life without applying for one because my parents are all deceased and i do not have either of their documents

Comment: *have lived all my life* **where**? Are you South African? If so, this is an off-topic question (not about expats).

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need your parents’ documents, just a certified copy of your birth certificate http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/civic-services/identity-documents